# Keyword not supported: 'name'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

So I'm going through this tutorial that seems so simple but I can't seem to get it to work.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489

This is the error I'm receiving when running my app: "Keyword not supported: 'name'."

Now I've looked at other posts similar to mine and it seemed like the connection string was the issue. So I looked closely at but can't see any real differences.

```
    <add name="BBCommercialSolutionsEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BBCommercialSolutions.csdl|res://*/Models.BBCommercialSolutions.ssdl|res://*/Models.BBCommercialSolutions.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYSOURCENAME;initial catalog=MYDATABASENAME;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

In my CompanyController.cs class, I receive the error when using the .ToList().

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //return View();
        using (var db = new BBCommercialSolutionsEntities())
        {
            //return View(db.BBCSCompanies.ToList());
            var tbl = db.BBCSCompanies;

            var list = tbl.ToList();

            return View(tbl.ToList());
        }
    }
```

And "new BBCommercialSolutionsEntities()" goes to my auto-generated template

```
    public BBCommercialSolutionsEntities()
        : base("name=BBCommercialSolutionsEntities")
    {
    }
```

Any ideas, thoughts, explanations, rants would help.

Comment: Why are you accessing data in your controller?

Comment: @AntonyScott - He might just be testing and messing around. He's following a tutorial so it's likely.

Comment: Yes I'm purely testing trying to get my feet wet with using MVC, but I'm probably going to use most of this test project for an internal app at work.

Comment: It's a little hardcore - but you could download debugging symbols .NET 4.0 (EF is part of .NET 4.0) and step into the code - might be fast to find the problem - or take a very long time. IIRC all you need to do is check a couple checkboxes in the Editor Options that let it download debugging symbols.

Comment: Cheers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Comment: Please don't add " MVC3" to the end of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: What class does BBCommercialSolutionsEntities extend, just so I don't make any assumptions?

Comment: Hey thanks for the link @JoshuaEnfield. I definitely learned something new!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use BBCommercialSolutionsEntities

```
public BBCommercialSolutionsEntities() : base("BBCommercialSolutionsEntities")
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm now getting this error: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed." I'll have to do some more poking around on the forums.

Comment: Your provider as in connection string is 

providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

Make sure you have .NET Framework installed correctly. You are using EF Code First. Aparat from official releases there are several EF versions floating around unfortunately :(

Comment: I did some further research and was using the wrong Framework. I downloaded the correct framework here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/11/ef-4-1-released.aspx. Everything's seems to be working good now. Thanks!